# Can't save and retrieve image in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio

I am working in fragments in android studio and In it I was trying to pick an image from gallery by clicking a button then save it and then again retrieve it  when I again launch the app.Here is my code of picking image from gallery after clicking the button and saving and retrieving it.

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_homepage, container, false);
    iv = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.profileImageView);
    location=(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.textView9);
    iv.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            openGallery();

        }
    });

  retrieveImage();



 return view;
}


private void openGallery() {
    Intent photoPickerIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    photoPickerIntent.setType("image/*");
   startActivityForResult(photoPickerIntent, 1);

}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    try
    {
        if (requestCode==RESULT_OK){
          String path=getPathFromCameraData(data,getActivity());
            Bitmap bmp=BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path);
            iv.setImageBitmap(bmp);
            storeImage(bmp);
        }
} catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private String getPathFromCameraData(Intent data, Context context) {
    Uri selectImage=data.getData();
    String[] filepathColumn={MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};
    Cursor cursor=context.getContentResolver().query(selectImage, filepathColumn, null, null, null);
    assert cursor != null;
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    int columnIndx=cursor.getColumnIndex(filepathColumn[0]);
    String piturepath=cursor.getString(columnIndx);
    cursor.close();

    return piturepath;

}
private boolean storeImage(Bitmap bitmap) throws IOException {
    OutputStream outputStream=null ;
    String directory=Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();



    File file=new File(directory,"/friend");
    if (file.exists())file.delete();
    try{


        outputStream = new FileOutputStream(file);
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, outputStream);
        outputStream.close();
        MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(getActivity().getContentResolver(),file.getAbsolutePath(),file.getName(),file.getName());
    }
    catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }



    return true;

    }
public boolean retrieveImage(){
    File f = new File(android.os.Environment.getDataDirectory() + "profile.jpg");
    Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(f.getAbsolutePath());
    iv.setImageBitmap(bmp);
    return  true;

}
```

Comment: did you checked ? image is physically at exist at your prefered location or not?
when you are retring image you hit this path  android.os.Environment.getDataDirectory() + "profile.jpg"

and while you are storeing you set this "/friend" directory might be its miss match

Comment: if you are picking image from gallery then why are you saving it again. Just keep that uri and load image from that uri again when needed

Comment: @VivekMishra is guide you on the right track if you need copy a image for specific purpose then you have to do your code other wise follow him advise

Comment: you just have to store addresses of image which you pick from gallery..
and show it on UI after fetching  from gallery while you need it.

Comment: I don't want to use it for some specific purpose.How can i store the address ?

Comment: Then you must have to go with this way.

Comment: In the onActivityResult you get the path of image while you come back right. you need to make a batabase and store it in database if you working with  more than one image  otherwise  you can take shared preference.
this way means stored images and display it when you need it.

Comment: you already have that path in onActivityResult nd if you have to show only one image at a time then save that string in shared preferences and if you want multiple then create a list of it and then save them

Comment: Can you edit my code and show me how to do it?

Comment: Do you have a single image or multiple

Comment: I want to use single image.